# Esconder codigo provado javascript

Tags: javascript

Faço acesso a um link externo do google e uso uma key particular, por exemplo:

```
 $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&maxResults=1&q=brksedu&key=(MINHA KEY AQUI)",
            success: function(e)
```

Minha pergunta é : como esconder essa key para que quem olhe o codigo fonte nao a veja? Coloca-la em uma variavel?

Obrigado!!!

Comment: Impossível esconder. Pode passar o dia ofuscando, que em menos de um minuto qualquer um olha pelo inspetor do browser.  O que pode fazer é acessar o painel da API e tentar restringir a funcionar só no domínio certo, que é o jeito mais normal de resolver.

Comment: Você pode fazer o ajax ir para seu código do backend, e fazer com que seu código pegue o retorno desse script e retorne via ajax. Então as variáveis vão ficar todas no backend. Vai elevar o custo de processamento mas sua chave fica escondida.

Comment: @PhiterFernandes dá na mesma. Se o JS requisita, qualquer um requisita.

Comment: Não mesmo. Esse código da questão seria executado no servidor, o cliente só veria a url do script.

Comment: @PhiterFernandes bom, se passar a consulta toda para o servidor, e fornecer só o resultado, você tem razão, mas aí precisa ver o quanto o tráfego duplo vai pesar pro Thiago (google <-> servidor, servidor <-> cliente),. E nesse caso, é importante que o Thiago entenda como reescrever a arquitetura toda.

Comment: Galera, vlw pelas respostas. Restringir o dominio é o que me resolve. O proprio google dá essa opção aqui e entao so meu dominio pode usar essa chave. Mesmo que outra pessoa a copie, não vai conseguir usar fora do meu dominio, acho! Vlw!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Impossível esconder informações no lado do cliente.
Entenda que tudo que o browser pode ver, o usuário também pode

A minha sugestão é colocar a key em algum codigo server-side (php, nodejs, python ou o que você estiver mais confortável com) e fazer requests nesse servidor (por ajax ou não)

lembre-se, finja que o usuário é seu pior inimigo em questões de segurança, deixe o menor numero de informações confidenciais possíveis na mão dele (se possível, nenhuma)